# Set contents of inline-flex div to bottom

Tags: html, css

Edit: this question is the victim of overzealous closure. I searched before posting and couldn't find anything that solved my issue. The correct solution, which someone has posted an answer for — `baseline`, only appears mid-way through a very long answer on the suggested 'duplicate'. Ridiculous moderation as usual.

I have two elements, `h2` and `p` inside a div. I have `display` set to `inline-flex`, as I want them both on the same line.

How do I get both elements to appear at the bottom of the div?

Currently, it looks like they are both in the middle:

[image]

My code is as follows — as you can see I've tried various things to try and align the elements to the bottom, but these don't work:

```html
<div class="title">
    <h2 style="margin-top: 0px;">Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p style="position: relative; bottom: 0;">smaller</p>
</div>
```

```css
.title {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  align-items: bottom;
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might help

```css
.title {
  display: inline-flex;
}

p,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>smaller</p>
</div>
```

---

if you want baseline of text to align

```css
.title {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>smaller</p>
</div>
```

---

Comment: Thank you, the second code (with `align-items: baseline;`) worked for me — [see image](https://i.imgur.com/4cV1vLt.png)